# pygtk: asynchronous output implemented with io_add_watch blocks when printing large output dataset

Tags: python, asynchronous, stream, gtk, pygtk

I'm writing a GTK+ GUI program with a python command line emulator. My python command line is implemented as a gtk.TextView, which can be used to output results of `prints` (and to read commands from TextView and `exec` them, but I don't post the input part here as it has nothing to do with the question).

I use the following technique to tee the `stdout` stream between the real terminal and my python command line:

```
r_out, w_out = os.pipe() # create a pipe, cause sys.stdout is unreadable, thus we can't poll it for available output
w_out_stream = os.fdopen(w_out, "w", 0) # open write-end of pipe with 0-length buffer
sys.stdout = w_out_stream # now prints and sys.stdout.writes would go to the pipe
watch = gobject.io_add_watch(r_out, gobject.IO_IN, stdout_callback) # poll the read-end of pipe for data and call stdout_callback

def stdout_callback(stream, condition):
    data = os.read(stream, 1) # read the pipe byte-by-byte
    iter = textbuf.get_end_iter() # textbuf is buffer of TextView, the GUI widget, I use as python command line
    textbuf.insert(iter, data) # output stdout to GUI
    sys.__stdout__.write(data) # output stdout to "real" terminal stdout

gtk.main()
```

This works pretty nice with small output. But unfortunately, when the output becomes relatively large (like thousands of bytes), my application hangs and doesn't display any output.

However, if I send a `SIGINT`, my output appears both in GUI and in real terminal. Obviously, I want it there without SIGINT. Any ideas, what causes such a block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The external process is blocking the UI while using os.read, you should spawn the process using glib.spawn_async and use a IOChannel to read the input something like:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GLib

class MySpawned(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)

        vb = Gtk.VBox(False, 5)
        self.tw = Gtk.TextView()
        bt = Gtk.Button('Run')
        bt.connect('clicked', self.process)

        vb.pack_start(self.tw, True, True, 0)
        vb.pack_start(bt, False, False, 0)

        self.add(vb)
        self.set_size_request(200, 300)
        self.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
        self.show_all()

    def run(self):
        Gtk.main()

    def process(self, widget, data=None):
        params = ['python', '-h']

        def write_to_textview(io, condition):
            print condition
            if condition is GLib.IO_IN:
               line = io.readline()
               self.tw.props.buffer.insert_at_cursor(line)
               return True
            elif condition is GLib.IO_HUP|GLib.IO_IN:
                GLib.source_remove(self.source_id)
                return False

        self.source_id = None

        pid, stdin, stdout, stderr = GLib.spawn_async(params,
                                        flags=GLib.SpawnFlags.SEARCH_PATH,                                       
                                        standard_output=True)

        io = GLib.IOChannel(stdout)

        self.source_id = io.add_watch(GLib.IO_IN|GLib.IO_HUP,
                                 write_to_textview,
                                 priority=GLib.PRIORITY_HIGH)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = MySpawned()
    s.run()
```

There are like a gazillion threads out there telling you that you could use threads or other stuff, please don't do that, the above example will not block you UI even on a long process and the output will be printed on the textview, works on windows too (but it will open an ugly console window until a bug in GLib will get fixed).

Comment: I guess, I found the source of block - call to `print` is blocking and when it fills up the pipe buffer, the whole thing gets stuck. Actually, I wasn't starting a separate python process, I just `exec` statements in a specially created namespace within the same main process. In my case I can just override sys.stdout object's write method with my own, my solution was an overkill. But thanks for a nice example, I'll use it as a reference for future.